# React dynamic meta tags with php yii v1.1

Tags: reactjs, yii, react-router, meta-tags, react-helmet

I'm building a new frontend with reactjs for movies directory website where PHP (Yii 1.1) was used as a backend technology. 
All data for meta tags are stored in the database and I would like to know what should I use with Yii 1 in order to build dynamic meta tags which will be discoverable by social networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Frontend you can use [react-document-meta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta).

Get your meta object from api and pass that value to `<DocumentMeta />` imported from `react-document-meta`

```
const meta = {
    title: 'Some Meta Title',
    description: 'I am a description, and I can create multiple tags',
    canonical: 'http://example.com/path/to/page',
    meta: {
        charset: 'utf-8',
        name: {
            keywords: 'react,meta,document,html,tags'
        }
    }
}
```

In Render method write:

```
    <DocumentMeta {...meta} />
```

> Note that social networks can't read this meta tags and if you do it with javascript it will be unaccessible for them.
>   Meta tags should be loaded in html code from backend to be accessible for social networks

Solutions to write meta tags with php on backend is to load html with php or use SSR (Server Side Rendering). Both of them causes refreshing your site.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Refreshing is the thing that I am trying to avoid. I was also considering react helmet, but it seems that helmet also has certain issues with social networks...